# Is there a way to reduce the active hours in Windows

Tags: windows-10, auto-updates

For Windows Updates, the maximum time you can select for active hours is 18.  I have used 18.  And I check for updates manually twice a day.  Yet it manages to reboot the PC when I have some downloads in progress.

I am hoping there may be a registry setting that I could change to increase the active hours to something like 23.

[image]

Comment: There is not, but you can constantly update your active hours with a schedule task.

Comment: You cannot do that. 12 - 15 active hours works for most of us. I have been using Active Hours for 5 years or more with no issue.

Comment: 1. Open `gpedit` 2. Go to `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Template > Windows Components > Windows Update` 3. Open `Turn off auto-restart for updates during active hours` 4. Set `Enable` 5. Set hours

Comment: Use `regedit` to navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings​` and set `SmartActiveHoursState` to `1` and then `ActiveHoursStart` and `ActiveHoursEnd`. Reboot might be required.